# Errors with ggplot2 since upgrading R from 3.01 to 3.02

Tags: r

I had a simple ggplot performing a Loess smooth fit and it used to work on 3.01 - now on 3.02 I'm getting this error:

```
geom_smooth: Only one unique x value each group.Maybe you want aes(group = 1)?
  Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero
```

Has anyone seen this - or have any idea how to resolve?

Heres the ggplot code:

```
  ggplot(data = x, aes(PDATETIME,MEAS_AVG))+ 
  ggtitle(MyTitle) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1),plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1))) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=factor(outlier)), size = 3) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.75, size = 1) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=x$TARG_AVG,colour = "green") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=ChartLine,colour = "red", linetype = 2) + 
  geom_line(data = x,aes(x=PDATETIME, y=UCL)) + 
  xlab("PDATETIME OF HIST")+ 
  ylab("MEAS_AVG OF HIST")
```

Line 5 causes the error - if I comment out, it works but with no LOESS fit obviously and it has an ugly x Axis, the date is not in months like it used to be in 3.01..

I know I haven't included the code that produces DF x so at this point I'm just looking to understand if 3.02 has been problematic for others.

Comment: Make sure your `x` variable (`PDADATETIME`) is not a factor or character. This looks like it's not formatted as a number/date (including the ugly axis).

Comment: Thanks - I was using mode() to check the datatype of the Vector - I should have been using class() or str()..this would have shown me the problem. Exactly as you described - PDATETIME was a factor instead of a POSIX......point to note if you save a DF to your C drive thrn call it back - it doesn't alway keep the cols in the same datatype as they were before you saved them. This is what caught me our - R is attempting to 'convert' to the most efficient type.....I'm sure everyone knows this - I didn't..!